# Contact form 7 datepicker depending on a textfield value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've created a form with a text field showing a date with this format: dd/mm/yyyy, and then I have a datepicker.

**This Contact form 7 datepicker should have a mindate depending on the textfield value.**

Actually I have only this code on the datepicker, because I need only Thursday are enabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
      $("#code").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [day == 4];
      }});
    });
</script>
```

Text field code ([showparam fecha] is a shortcode depending on an URL parameter):

```
<input name="date-start" id:"date-start" value="[showparam fecha]" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false" type="text" disabled>
```

Datepicker code:

```
[date* date-end id:code date-format:mm/dd/yyyy min-date:0 max-date:31/12/2017]
```

Image:

[Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeH47.png)

Any idea?

Thank you so much
Luis

Comment: This is not an answer but an alternative. You can use HTML5 datepicker instead - `<input type="date"/>`